# How to mix PHP and Javascript variables, if at all?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I'm going to try to keep this as simple as I can but it's a doozy. I'm getting data from MySQL using PHP and I'm creating variables for fantasy football league info.  A user could have data stored for one fantasy league, or he could have added data for 20 leagues.  So when the ADD TEAM page loads, I get the data (with a standard mysql query that works fine) for ALL of the user's leagues and create variables with a number appended to each variable to keep them unique...

```
        $l=1;
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($savedleagues)) {
           ${"leaguescode".$l} = "<option value='$l'>". $row['fantasyleaguename'] . "</option>";
           ${"leaguetype".$l}=$row['leaguetype'];
           ${"leaguescoring".$l}=$row['scoring'];
           ${"leaguewebsite".$l}=$row['leaguewebsite'];
        $l++;
        }
```

So after this is done, say the user had THREE leagues saved.  There would now be PHP variables like...

```
$leaguescode1="<option value='1'>My Brothas League</option>"
$leaguetype1="redraft";
$leaguescoring1="std";
$leaguewebsite1="ESPN";
$leaguescode2="<option value='2'>Fake Football League</option>"
$leaguetype2="keeper";
$leaguescoring2="ppr";
$leaguewebsite2="CBS";
$leaguescode3="<option value='3'>Best League Ever</option>"
$leaguetype3="redraft";
$leaguescoring3="ppr";
$leaguewebsite3="Yahoo";
```

Still with me?  Wow, thank you, let's continue...

All that variable creation is done as the ADD TEAM page loads.  On the ADD TEAM page, there is a select option to use default settings from one of the leagues they might have entered earlier. So in our example, the user would have a dropdown with the THREE leagues he entered as available options.  If he chose the league called "Best League Ever", it would automatically change the league type to Re-Draft, the scoring option to PPR, and the website to Yahoo (on the form on the ADD TEAM page).  The Select option is generated like this...

```
echo "<div id='league' class='question'><span class='bold'>Assign to League?:</span>
         <select name='fantasyleague' id='fantasyleague' onChange='setLeagueDefaults(this);'>
         <option value='0'>Not assigned</option>";
         for ($i=1; $i<$l; $i++) {
             echo ${"leaguescode".$i};
         }
        echo "</select>
        </div>";
```

As you can see, I want the settings to change when the user changes the select option by using...

```
onChange='setLeagueDefaults(this);'
```

So if they chose league 3 (best league ever), it would pass "3", which I then want to use in the javascript below...

```
function setLeagueDefaults(sel) {
        var leaguenum = sel.value;  

        document.getElementById("<?php echo ${"leaguescoring".leaguenum};?>").checked = true;

}
```

Before you rightfully yell at me, I know my problem is with the PHP code nested inside the Javascript. Pretty sure it's horrible practice to mix php and javascript, but at a loss as to how else to approach this.

Simply put example wise, I want to pass the data stored in the PHP variable $leaguescoring3 (which is "ppr") into the bit of javascript above to change the league scoring radio button to be the PPR option (**because it has an ID of "ppr"**).  So when all is said and done, I'd like it to appear in the code as...

```
document.getElementById("ppr").checked = true;
```

I'm getting extremely confused trying to put that javascript variable (called "leaguenum", which is storing the proper select value btw) back into the PHP snippet.  Seems very wrong/stupid, so I must be going about this the wrong way.

If anyone is smart/crazy enough to understand what Im trying to explain, and can point me in a better direction, please let me know.

Any help with any aspect of this would be completely appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: JSON and AJAX is where its at. Google it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) and print it into a `<script>` tag

```
<?php $test = "Hello world!"; ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
var test = <?php print(json_encode($test)); ?>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
<div id="test" style="display:none">
<?php
echo json_encode($myPhpData);
?>
</div>
```

Then take the json from this div with something like:

```
var obj = $.parseJSON($('div#test').html());
```